# CKEditorError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm trying to build a webpage to perform CRUD operations. I'm getting an error on collecting data from Ckeditor to post in Json server in React.

> This is the Error-

[image]

> This is my code -
>
> > Note: Note: This Code is Working fine for normal input form but in the Ckeditor section it's not working

```
import { useHistory, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from '../Header/Header';
import bgpic from './a215_1_cover_image.jpg';

import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

const AddPost = () => {
  let history = useHistory();
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    title: '',
    img: '',
    body: '',
  });

  const { title, img, body } = user;

  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/post', user);
    history.push('/');
  };
return (
    <>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='w-75 mx-auto shadow p-5'>
          <h2 className='text-center mb-4'>Your Blog</h2>

          <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
            <div className='form-group'>
              <input
                type='text'
                required
                className='form-control form-control-lg'
                placeholder='Title'
                name='title'
                value={title}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
              />
            </div>

            <div className='form-group'>
              <CKEditor
                name='body'
                value={body}
                editor={ClassicEditor}
                onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}></CKEditor>
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddPost;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per CKEditor Documentation [Quick Start](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html#quick-start)

You can access editor's data using **editor.getData()** method

Also, you need to change the props **value** to **data** instead

It would be like this:

```
<CKEditor
  name="body"
  data={body}
  editor={ClassicEditor}
  onChange={(e, editor) => {
    setUser({
      ...user,
      body: editor.getData(),
    });
  }}
></CKEditor>
```

Comment: Thanks , it's working! But It's parsing with html tag. I've tried to use  ```ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser'``` but it's not working. Can you tell me how can I parse Html data to normal text

Comment: If you mean to render the editor.getData() response

Try using dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }}
Ex:
              <div
                className="box-content"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: body }}
              ></div>

Comment: If i want to insert an image inside of text editor and push it in json server along with other text, what would be the easiest option and how can I do that? (Easy Image, Ck finder,  Base64 upload)